# Is both merger are same in Pandas asof & Polars join

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-polars

Is both are same pandas merge_asof & ploars join.
Is both are given same out put or not.

Comment: polars seems to include `asof` as one of the possible [`join`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html) types (see doc). That said, why don't you try with a simple example first?

Comment: I think you should try to run the code first, or read their documents.

Comment: Yes am read the document and try to perform operation but, after mergegot different types of data frame , But in doc of polars writen bath are same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am try to execute several time to execute to check both merger are same or not but i got result is :
Both Are not same.